# How to close a WPF application when visual studio is closed?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, add-in

My requirement:

I have a visual studio 2013 instance, and side by I have a WPF Tool application running. This WPF tool application is added as a customized add-in tool in visual studio. So basically, whenever I select this WPF tool application from the "Tools" option of visual studio instance, this WPF tool application runs( WPF window is shown, in simple terms).
Now whenever I close this visual studio instance, I want to detect this closure, and accordingly close my WPF tool application.

So basically, In my code of WPF tool application, how do I detect the closure of the corresponding Visual studio instance, and according thereafter close this WPF application window?

Comment: You are going to need to look at the processes that are running on the machine. `System.Diagnostics.Process` is a good place to start. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You can Create one timer and in that timer tick event in your wpf application which will continuosly checking for running instance of visual studio 2013 and if it is not running then also shutdown your application.

Comment: Have you registered your Tool? From the [Tool Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165073.aspx) page on MSDN: *To provide a tool window, you must register it with Visual Studio and specify its default size and location... After a single-instance tool window is opened, it remains open until the IDE is closed.*

Comment: Thank you. Identifying the process and in background initiating timer to check for the same should work.